# jQuery: getJSON vs get, http headers? (Twitter API)

Tags: ajax, jquery

Hey all. I'm using the Twitter API via javascript and I'm firing a call to `user_timeline.json`. Everything seems to work fine with `jQuery.getJSON` but I'd really like to get the response as a string without it being converted into objects, which `getJSON` does. When I change my method from `getJSON` to `get`, I get the following error in Chrome:

```
Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Which seems to be caused by the lacking of an Accept header. Am I correct? If so, how can I specify an HTTP header for the raw `get` method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only when you use JSON are you allowed to query domains different than the originating, with Ajax. (*for security reasons*)

See

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy
- https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

You will need to use a server proxy to do this.

---

If you want the actual JSON in string format then just re-stringify it.

Use https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js and call `var jsonString = JSON.stringify( yourJsonObject );`

Answer (score 3):

You can't get it as raw text, the way the whole thing works is JSONP, which creates a `<script>` tag, and the data that comes back is actual JavaScript, like this:

```
myFunc({ ...data ... });
```

It's not jQuery converting it to JSON here, it's actual JavaScript being called, where `myFunc` is your callback function...so the request is never text to deal with, it's a javascript object off the bat.